# java arraylist iteration

Tags: java

Is this going to cause unpredictable behavior?

```
 ArrayList<X> x = new ArrayList<>();
 //x.add(new X())...
f:
for(int i = 0; i < x.size() -1;)
{
      X y = x.get(i);
      for(int j = i + 1; j < x.size();)
       {
          if(a) {
           x.remove(j);
           continue;
          }
          if(b) {
           x.remove(i);
           continue f;
          }
          j++;
        }
       i++;
}
```

Comment: booleans dependent on values of x.get(j) and x.get(i); iterating without iterator and still removing is the question

Comment: `x.size()` should be called every time the `for's` condition is checked, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be unpredictable, but your style seems wrong to me, so your approach is suspect.

Using a label is a bad idea, and deciding to use it shows that your approach is flawed.

You may want to look at this discussion about deleting on ArrayList, but basically, LinkedList would be fsster:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t587893-best-way-to-loop-through-arraylist-and-remove-elements-on-the-way.html

But, removing this way will work.

**UPDATE:**

Oops, just saw a couple of bugs:

```
      if(a) {
       x.remove(j);
       continue;
      }
```

OK, in this one, you will go back through the loop for j, but you didn't increment j.

```
      if(b) {
       x.remove(i);
       continue f;
      }
```

This is the same for i.

So, you need a similar change to fix it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x.size() -1; i++)
```

This way, when you hit `continue` then it will still go to the next element.

Comment: java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source) that's one of the stack traces, the rest are all stuck inside that loop written in the question. so just suspected something might be wrong with it.

Comment: i'm not seeing the problem. if you remove something why do you need to increment.

Comment: I tend to just remove from the first position, removing from elsewhere has been a problem for me in the past.  I think you may want to reconsider your design, as it is flawed, and you will waste time trying to fix it, rather than just redesigning it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to create an `array` which contains indexes to remove.
And fill it with indexes in the main `for` cycle. Than you can do something like this:

```
Collections.sort(indexesToRemoveArr);
Collections.reverse(indexesToRemoveArr);
for (int indexToRemove : indexesToRemoveArr) {
     arr.remove((int) indexToRemove );
}
```

In that code I remove indexes from end to start. That's why it won't do any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Compiler will optimize and call x.size() only once. So your terminatin condition becomes incorrect as soon as you remove element.